# Changing Clickable Area of an Image without Resizing Image

Tags: javascript, php, css, button, click

I am currently working on a PHP/Javascript project where an action occurs when an image is clicked.  The image is small, so I would like to expand the clickable area to further around the image without  enlarging the image itself.  Is this possible?  Below is a general idea of the structure of what I'm working on.

```
<g id="pictures">
 <image id="marker_image" cx="145" cy="460" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none"
 x="136" y="451" width="18" height="18" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xlink:href="//link.thislink.com/image_assets/markers/pool.png" 
 style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" 
 stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-
 linejoin="round"></image>
</g>
```

I'm new to working with SVGs, but from what I've read, I think I can use the `<g>` to add padding?

Comment: You should add the html. If the clickable area is a block or inline-block element, you can add padding.

Comment: Please include the minimal amount of code to reproduce your problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Aaron Added some code

Comment: `<g>` element doesn't render in the dom, so you won't be able to add padding, it also doesn't look as though your using an svg, but rather a .png

Comment: @Aaron Oh, okay. That makes sense. Would it make sense to add padding the image element?

Comment: you should be able to add padding to the `#marker_image` yes.

Comment: @Aaron I added `padding: 100px;`, but it does not seem to have affected the clickable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you image in a `div`, make the div as big as you want using padding, and bind your action on the div instead of the img

Comment: Since it's in a <g> would I be able to add the padding there?  I'm new to SVG

Comment: your <g> should be placed inside a <div> like <div><g>stuff goes here</g></div>

I also guess you have a javascript function that does specific stuff, so bind your fonction on the div like <div onclick="myFunction()" >. Also your div will be as big as your image, so you got to add padding with CSS, this way the div gonna expand ( use padding:10px; if you want to keep your image centered into the div ) and you'll have a bigger clickable surface

Comment: I didn't show it in the code above, but there is more images in the `<g>` then just the one.  Am I not able to add the padding directly to the image?

Comment: that is why i'm telling you to surround your <g> tag with a <div> tag and add padding ON the <div>, not on the <g>

Comment: But wouldn't that add padding to every item in the `<g>` tag?

Comment: No it would add padding to the div only, why would it add padding to <g> tag ? If you only give padding to this div, only this div will have padding. Not it's children

Comment: I suggest that you go read this [W3C link about padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) for better understanding what are paddings and how it can help you for this specific situations

Comment: I understand what padding is, but I guess what I'm not understanding is if I have this structure: `<div><g><image></image><image div="marker_image"></image></g></div>` how will that only affect the image I want, `#marker_image`?

Comment: I maybe wasnt clear, this is the structure you got : <g><image id="marker_image"></image></g> right ? i was suggesting you to surround this with a div tag such as : <div><g><image id="marker_image"></image></g></div>.

The div will be the same size of your <g>, but if you give it padding, it will expand from the inside, like if you were inflating a baloon. This way the div gonna be bigger.

Comment: No, I get that. But there's multiple images within the <g> and I only want padding on some of them. The div wouldn't add padding to only the specific images I want, correct?  Front end has never been my strong point -_-

Comment: then inside the <g> surround the <image></image> where you want specific padding with a <div>. Like this : 

<g>
<div class="paddingDiv"><image></image></div>
<image></image>
<div class="paddingDiv"><image></image></div>
<image></image>
</g>

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101795/discussion-between-jorel-loki-amthor-and-tibsar).